# Dimensions of submatrices in a block matrix with identity submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose
$$M=\begin{pmatrix}A&I\\I&C\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A$ is a $p×q$ matrix. What are the dimensions of $C$?

Would $C$ be $p×q$ as well?

Someone told me the answer was $q×p$ but I still think that it is $p×q$.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning? Have you tried to draw some example matrices for some values of $p$ and $q$, like $p=2$ and $q=3$ for example?

Comment: @angryavian I'm not sure, I thought the block matrices must have same row with block rows and same column with block columns, which makes it plausible for C to also be p rows and q columns.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that all identity matrices are square. As such, the $I$ below $A$ is of dimensions $q×q$ and that which is right of $A$ has dimensions $p×p$, as this is a *block* matrix. It follows that $C$ has dimensions $q×p$.

Answer (score 2):

The top right is an identity matrix, which has the same number of rows as columns.  It has the same number of rows as $A$, namely $p$, so $p$ columns,
and this is the same number of columns as in $C$.
Similarly, the bottom left being an identity matrix, 
$C$ has the same number of rows as $A$ has columns, namely $q$.

Comment: omg right, I totally forgot that Identity matrices were square. I just remembered that they had all 0's except 1's diagonally.